# Jquery drop down submenu not allow me to click on submenu items

Tags: jquery, html, css, menu, submenu

This is html code for menu and submenu in which i declared the ul and li items for creating menu items.When i hover cursor on "home" it's slide down the submenu and when i try to click on submenu item it's sliding it up.

```
<nav id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">11th</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">11th</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|</a></li>
        <li><a href="testimonials.html">Testimonials &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|</a></li>
        <li><a href="news.html">News + Article &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

**CSS CODE**
This is css code where i style the menu and submenu and also work for submenu.

```
#nav{background: #1a1511; height: 50px;}
#nav li li:hover{background: #ccc; cursor: pointer;}
#nav ul, #nav li{list-style-type: none; padding:0; margin:0;}
#nav li{float: left; width: 160px; line-height: 50px; list-style-type: none; text-align: center;}
#nav li ul{position: absolute; background: #1a1511; display: none; }
#nav li li{float: none; padding: 2px;}
#nav a{color: #fff; text-decoration: none;}
```

**js code**

```
$(function(){
        $("#nav li").hover(function(){

            $(this).find("ul").slideToggle('medium');
        });

        var submenu = $("li > ul > li");

        submenu.hover(function(){
            $(this).find("ul").slideToggle(200);
        });
});
```

Comment: Why don't you just use bootstrap: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar

Comment: thanx for your suggestion but i want to code it my own for make my programming skills strong.

Comment: you still can improve your programming skills by using free and wide spread libraries like bootstrap, because people will see your work not your skills ;)